Possible way to show that Equation has infinite many solutions
I was thinking about a way to prove that an equation has infinitely many solutions, but I'm not sure if it's a valid assumption. Maybe someone can help. The equation is:
$$5bn+8k+8kn-8n-3b = 8kn^2+8n;\quad b=2^n;\quad n,k \in ℤ, k>n\ge4$$
In the first step, I reduce the equation modulo 5 and modulo 3.
1)
$$5bn+8k+8kn-8n-3b \equiv 8kn^2+8n \pmod 5$$
$$3k+3kn-3n-3b \equiv 3kn^2+3n \pmod5 $$
$$3*(k+kn-n-b) \equiv 3*(kn^2+n) \pmod 5$$
$$=> 5m_1 + k+kn-b-n = 5m_2 +kn^2+n$$
$$5(m_1-m_2)=kn^2-kn+b-k+2n \quad m_1>m_2 $$
For (modulo 3) we can do the same and get:
$$3*(l_1-l_2) +bn = kn^2-kn+2n-k \quad l_1>l_2$$
The right-hand side can now be substituted into the equation modulo 5, which leads to the equation:
$$5(m_1-m_2) = 3(l_1-l_2)+bn+b \quad |\; m_1-m_2 =x \;;\;l_1-l_2 =y $$
$$5y -3x =b(n+1) \quad \quad (F)$$
From the linear Diophantine equation, we know that $$Ax+By=c$$
has infinitely many solutions if $\gcd(A,B)\;|\;c$.
Since $\gcd(5,-3) = 1$ and $1\;|\;b(n+1)$, the euqation $(F)$ also has infinitely many solutions.

Does this work to show that the equation has infinitely many solutions or did I misinterpret or describe something incorrectly mathematically?

Thy $n^2$ and the $2^n$ make this not a linear equation. And neither $b$ nor $n$ are constants.

Okay, I think I understand what you mean. So the first part was just an attempt to transform the first equation into a simpler form, which led to (F). And although b is not linear, does that really matter for the equation$(F)$? Because the right-hand side can be treated as a constant integer when n is chosen. $x$ and $y$ are just differences of integers, so they satisfy the conditions for such an equation. Since gcd(a,b)=1, it always divides c =b(n+1), which is why there should be infinitely many solutions to equation (F) for any n, and therefore also for the first equation.

Where does this question come from? Any context would be appreciated. Do you have any reason to believe that there are infinitely many solutions? Or any solutions at all, for that matter?

if the equation has infinitely solutions for n, there would be infinitely many twin primes. I tried many things to show that there are infinitely many solutions to the equation, but either it led to a contradiction or I got stuck. I tried using elliptic curves, trying to convert the equation into Pell's equation, but that also resulted in contradictions. Since I'm not well-versed in the field, I didn't expect much else. My last attempt was this one, trying to use modular arithmetic to find possible solutions that could be proven and then also apply to the first one. But this was unsuccessful

This does not work because this is not a linear Diophantine equation. A linear Diophantine equation in the variables $k$ and $n$ is of the form
$$Ak+Bn=C,$$
for some fixed integers $A$, $B$ and $C$. Your equation has terms such as $2^n$ and $kn^2$, making it nonlinear. In fact what you've shown so far is that there are infinitely many integers $x$, $y$ and $n$ such that
$$5x-3y=2^n(n+1),$$
but this is rather trivial because every integer $m$ can be expressed as $5x-3y=m$ for some integers $x$ and $y$. It remains to show that there are infinitely many $n$ for which there is an integer $k>n$ such that we can take
$$x=kn^2-kn-k+2n+2^n,\qquad y=kn^2-kn-k+2n-2^nn,$$
which is not really any progress from the original problem.
The first thing to note is that your equation is linear in $k$. We can express it as
$$k(8+8n-8n^2)+(5n-3)2^n-16n=0,$$
or equivalently, because $8+8n-8n^2\neq0$ for all integers $n$, and because $n\geq4$, we can express it as
$$k=2\frac{2^{n-4}(5n-3)-n}{n^2-n-1},$$
where both the numerator and denominator of the fraction on the right hand side are integers, and the denominator is odd for all $n$. So your question is equivalent to asking:

Are there infinitely many integers $n\geq4$ such that $n^2-n-1$ divides $2^{n-4}(5n-3)-n$?

I do not see any viable approach. A computer search yields no solutions with $n<10^6$.
